# Can't select and delete an object

Tags: rendering

Okay, so this thing, is for me very strange. It still might be very obvious, but I started with blender 4 days ago.

So what is happening is that when I am rendering my animation, I have a white wall and ground where the scene grid is.

Here is a screenshot when in render mode: [image]

And here it is in material mode: [image]

I would really like to remove this, and I have tried for hours now with no success. I tried to unlink "world" from the scene but then it got all dark when rendered.

If you have any idea of what could be causing this?

(I am making an animated minecraft intro)

Edit: I was told to do alt + h and then the wall and the ground was visible in material mode as well. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

But I can't find a way to delete it...  :/

Comment: Try `Alt`+`H` to un-hide objects in the viewport.

Comment: Ok, now the wall and ground is showing in material mode.

Comment: It looks like a hidden object. The *world* datablock can't have any mesh data, so it doesn't really make sense for an object to be *in* it. If you can't select it in the 3D view with RMB, then look in the outliner for an object with selection disabled (mouse pointer icon).

Answer (score 9):

Not a bug, no black magic needed to get rid of the object.

What you have is an object that cannot be selected. The **selectable** switch has been disabled.

[image]

Enable that, select the object and delete it!

Those icons on the outliner are toggle switches:

**Eye** to make the object **visible** in the viewport.

**Arrow** for **selectability**

**Camera** to enable the object for **rendering**.

Make yourself a favor and read the manual page for the outliner here: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html

Comment: Is there a shortcut for it like with the Eye and Camera options?

Comment: It makes sence, I believed I tried that on actually every object in the scene.. But I might have missed that one, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to entirely disable World (although you can make it functionally do nothing.) However, you don't need to, because the piece you are having issues with is not World. World contains no geometry, it is only your background color. The piece shown in your images is a piece of geometry, and should be deletable like any other. You just have to find where it is and what its called. Try looking in the Outliner, and keep in mind that if the Arrow (looks like a mouse pointer) next to something is disabled, then it cannot be selected until you re-enable it. It could also be hiding on other render layers.

If you share your file, we can help you figure out the problem piece.
EDIT: Upon reviewing file, it was a piece called "Plane".

Comment: Here  is the file
http://www.mediafire.com/download/b92gnjzu3eamezc/shared.blend

Comment: I can't select it either. Very interesting. @drudge That isn't really an answer necesarily

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Let me know if you figure it out? (If you feel like trying of course) I am going to bed now so hopefully someone have come up with a solution tomorrow :/

Comment: I will, this is very odd behavior, so I'm afraid it might be a bug. I will be sure to let you know what I find though.

Comment: It is a piece simply called "Plane" that is set as unselectable in the outliner. Check the Arrow and you can then select and delete it. @NoviceInDisguise: It's an accurate answer to the original question, which was in regards to World. And it turns out to have been accurate to the real issue as well. I have updated it.

Comment: Good, that is fine then :D