# Blender rendering is grey and black

Tags: rendering

[image: rendered scene]

hello . how to get rid of this grey plane that hides my interior. in 3d view it doesnt appear but when i rendered it shows. I try to make some changes in render then camera setup.  please can anybody tell what to do.

Comment: Most likely it's hidden in the 3D view. Try pressing Alt H and see if it shows up.

Comment: May be this plane is on another layer?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stressed out about it. :) yes there was a plane :) finally its all okey :)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6857/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28315/599.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your object is hidden in the viewport, but not in the render. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the viewport to unhide all hidden objects, or examine the *outliner* for objects with their eye icon disabled:

[image]

The eye icon controls object visibility in the viewport and preview render, and the camera icon controls object visibility in the final render.