# Objects behind glass shader appear black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

Why is this Iris not showing? It worked previously, before I started working on the fur and particle system today and other parts of the model (a monkey model) and at the end I realised that the Iris disappeared. I haven't touched the eyeball, but now the iris doesn't show. I suspect that it has to do with the UVs, but everything is in place, I didn't tweak anything, it should work. I'm attaching a stripped down .blend (only the eyeball) and a screenshot. Can someone have a look into the file, and try to make the iris show?

I should also note, that when I open the previous file, it shows. But when I append that eyeball to the new file, it doesn't show.

[image: Eyeball]

[image]

Comment: Another example of the same issue: [Objects behind glass appear too dark](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/objects-behind-glass-appear-too-dark?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a glass shader for the cornea. 
Unfortunately that shader does not behave as expected when it comes to letting light through it...

You need to add some transparency to it in a node setup like this:

[image]

For a more detailed explanation read: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)