# Why is my glass rendering black with a circle reflection? Importing FBX into Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am extremely new to Blender, seeking to use it for architectural visualization for my fifth-year design studio. I am modelling in Revit, exporting as an FBX, and importing into Blender.

So far everything has taken PBR materials very well, except for the imported glass in both curtain walls and window families, such as below:

[image]

This was a quick test, only 128 samples, but I can't imagine more samples is the solution. Additionally a black ring is appearing on the floor of the renderings, which I imagine is a result of my glass. I am using an insanely simple node setup for the glass:

[image]

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

---

Wireframes and quick render below:

[image]
[image]

Bottom wireframe is from previous posts' render. Thanks again!

Comment: See if these help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66702/objects-behind-glass-shader-appear-black or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71570/why-is-there-no-light-passing-through-the-window . Otherwise post some wireframe images of your glass objects and what is behind them so we can diagnose.

Comment: The third link helped, especially the quality of light in my renders, but for some reason the issue still remains. Forgive me, but I'm going to add an answer to my own question really quick in order to show you wireframes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Answers are for answering the questions only, if you have further details either edit your original question, or post a new one

Comment: I need your node setup for the window to possibly diagnose the problem there. Looks to me like it's a material issue.

Comment: Which lights are you using, and where are they positioned?

Comment: I had the same issue and I think it was simply bad topology. I used the Remesh modifier with Octree 9 and unticked Remove Disconnected Pieces and it did the trick