# Light wont penetrate glass

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting

[image]

I just have a simple glass shader and that is it, is there anything i need to add so that light penetrates it? I'm using HDRI lighting and I have a sun lamp pointing directly at the glass.

Comment: Did you increase light paths bounces?

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/objects-behind-glass-appear-too-dark and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader