# Colour of iris doesn't show in render (cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0JyyWeptSA) on youtube for the procedural eyes of my sculpture. I used nodes to make them. When I render my sculpture, the colour of the iris doesn't show. However, when I render the eyes in the same file but outside of the head, the colour shows. I think it has something to do with the sclera and the way the light hits the eye. Maybe someone can help me with this problem.

[image: render of eyeball]

[image: render of eyeball in head sculpture]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/objects-behind-glass-appear-too-dark

Comment: thanks for the link! I tried to add the glass shader but it didn't change anything. The problem that the iris is grey/too dark only appears when I put the eye into its eye socket.