Eye creation: Transmission makes the pupil very dark
I am using transmission on my cornea mesh to reveal the pupil beneath it but the transmission is making the mesh underneath very dark. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? ive included a photo of what the pupil looks like with and without the cornea mesh.


file link:


Hello could you please pack the images and share your file?

What is the color setting of your glass material? Is is pure white or just the default 0.8 light grey? Set it to pure white, and increase the Max Bounces for Total, Glossy and Transmission in the Render Properties under Light Paths.

For more information how to get better glass materials see the answers here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277790/grey-artifacts-in-glass-bottle and here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/257836/glass-objects-surface-problem

@moonboots i just uploaded the file. the textures are packed into it

do you plan to use Cycles? It seems pretty ok in Cycles in Rendered preview mode, don't judge the result in Material preview mode because it is using Eevee and glass in Eevee will never be as good as in Cycles

@moonboots yes im using cycles, the pupil is much darker under the cornea than when the cornea is removed (as seen in the pictures). does it look darker on your end?

the iris looks darker but your eye globe diffuse image is not white, it's sepia, make it a bit brighter if you want the iris to look brighter?

The iris is darker than what you would like because the image plugged into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF is not white, it's yellowish, if you want it to be brighter, edit it in an image editor or put a Color > RGB Curve between the Image Texture node and the Principled BSDF and tweak the curve:


ill tweak the texture, thanks!
